# Why is sanding small car rust with "Dremel" superior to sanding with a drill?

Tags: tools, rust, sanding

In recommendations for sanding, one reads that a Dremel tool should be used.

This appears to be a recommendation for a particular brand, rather than for a particular RPM, or torque.

Is a Dremel tool superior to an ordinary drill because the rpm can reach 4000+ (whereas a drill might be around 1500), because the Dremel is miniature whereas a drill is bulky/heavy and unwieldy for finer work, because the sanding tools are sold in fixed-size diameter that fit the Dremel, or for a combination of the above?

The project in question is catching car rust when it's still tiny, before it spreads.

Comment: You have a lot more control with a dremel on small spots.

Comment: Like putting up a picture hook with a 14lb sledge.. :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dremel may be being used as a generic term like hoover, kenwood  or landrover...

But the higher speed and precision are the two characteristics that are good for (very) small areas of rust.